# With WordPress multi-language site in English and Spanish, Google doesn't index the URLs with the /es/

Tags: wordpress, url, search-engine-indexing, multilingual, internationalization

I have launched a website with English and Spanish languages. I've done it using WordPress multi-language (WPML), but I'm having a lot of problems indexing and ranking the Spanish URLs, which appear in the URL the `/es/`.

Google Search Console is declaring all URLS like `example.com/en/whatever` as "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical"

I really need these pages, despite being translations of the English version, to also index and rank keywords.

Comment: For each page, do you have the `lang` attribute set on your `html` element, and `link hreflang` tags in your `head` element?

Comment: Hi Stephen, yeah, all the pages are marked with the correct lang and hreflang. I´m really lost with that rpoblem

Comment: Are those pages 100% translated? Perhaps you could share an actual link for us to check?